# name 'randrange' is not defined ERROR, password generator

Tags: random, import, passwords, generator

I'm trying to code a password generator but it's not working and I can't understand the error.

```
import random
import string

lw = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
uw = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
ns = list(string.digits)
password = ""

def addLW():
    f = randrange(1, len(lw))
    password = password + lw[f]

def addUW():
    f = randrange(1, len(lw))
    password = password + uw[f]

def addN():
    f = randrange(1, len(lw))
    password = password + ns[f]

funcs = [addLW, addUW, addN]

maxx = input("Password generator.\nMax: ")

if maxx.isdigit():
    maxx = int(maxx)
    for i in range(maxx):
        func = random.choice(funcs)
        func()
    print(f"Password: {password}")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Password Generator.py", line 29, in <module>
    func()
  File "Password Generator.py", line 14, in addUW
    f = randrange(1, len(lw))
NameError: name 'randrange' is not defined
```

I don't understand because I've already imported 'random'...

Answer (score 7):

```
import random
```

You've imported `random`. That means your global namespace now contains the binding to the `random` namespace. It does *not* contain `randrange()` or anything else within that namespace, so you need to *explicitly* use `random.randrange()` if you want it to find that method.

You *can* bring `randrange` itself in to the global namespace with:

```
from random import randrange
```

but that suffers from a few issues:

- that *only* gives you `randrange()`, not any other stuff from `random`;
- it will quickly pollute your global namespace with names if you need other things; and
- it will get tedious if you want to import a large number of things (unless you import `*`, but see the previous bullet point about polluting the global namespace).